# Active pattern - Check list for consecutive elements

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive

So as a school assignment, I have to write a partial active pattern which recognizes a poker hand, for example:

```
let (|FullHouse|_|) (x: (string * string) list) =
    x
    |> List.groupBy snd
    |> List.sortByDescending fst
    |> List.forall (fun (_, v) -> v |> List.length > 1)
    |> function true -> Some () | _ -> None

let x6 =
    match [("S", "2"); ("S", "2"); ("S", "Q"); ("S", "Q"); ("S", "Q")] with
    | FullHouse -> sprintf "Full house"
    | _ -> "Nothing"
```

I have managed to do 6 out of the 9 hands, but I couldn't figure out how to check if the hand has a straight in it (the 5 values are consecutives, eg. 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). Is there a List. operator which can help me do this?

Comment: This question isn't really about active patterns. This could be a plain function and you would be having the same problem. It's useful to be able to split problems into smaller pieces so that you can ask more specific and relevant questions.

Comment: Try writing a function that takes just a list of card values and checks if they are consecutive and unique. Once you have tested that works on its own you should be able to use it in your current implementation. Hint: When you do `List.groupBy snd` you're grouping by the card value, not the suit. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I understand that, but I couldn't do that even in a separate function, because as you have said, it's still the same problem.

Comment: You might want to sort the list and then use [`List.pairwise`](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#13-partitioning-chunking-and-grouping) to divide the cards up into pairs. (The `pairwise` function turns `[1; 2; 3; 4]` into `[(1,2); (2,3); (3,4)]`). Then look for a property P that will be true of every such pair of cards if and *only* if the hand is a straight. Once you've figured out what that property P might be, you can write a function to check for it, and use `List.forall` on that list of pairs.

Comment: List.pairwise could be used to check if each item is consecutive. You'll need a custom sort function, too probably - to put the picture cards in the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from the comments, I managed to solve this issue and I am posting the solution here for anyone else having the same (or similar) problem.

```
let GiveValue (x: string) =
    match x with
    | "2" -> 2
    | "3" -> 3
    | "4" -> 4
    | "5" -> 5
    | "6" -> 6
    | "7" -> 7
    | "8" -> 8
    | "9" -> 9
    | "10" -> 10
    | "J" -> 11
    | "Q" -> 12
    | "K" -> 13
    | "A" -> 14
    | _ -> 0

let (|Straight|_|) (x: (string * string) list) =
    x
    |> List.map (fun (_, v) -> v)
    |> List.map GiveValue
    |> List.sort
    |> List.pairwise
    |> List.forall (fun (x, y) -> y-x = 1)
    |> function true -> Some () | _ -> None

let x4 =
    match [("S", "J"); ("D", "9"); ("S", "8"); ("S", "10"); ("S", "Q")] with
    | Straight -> sprintf "Straight"
    | _ -> "Nothing"
```

Comment: Looks good. One comment: `List.map (fun x -> GiveValue x)` can be shorted to just `List.map GiveValue`.